# How predict Future prices in C# .net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, prediction, ml.net

I want to predict the future prices on the basis of previous data
I want to make a web portal that shows the predicted prices.
I have Tried:
TimeSeries

```
    IDataView trainingDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(modelInputs);
            // Build training pipeline
            var dataProcessPipeline = mlContext.Forecasting.ForecastBySsa(
                 "Score",
                 nameof(ModelInput.priceA),
                 windowSize: 5,
                 seriesLength: 10,
                 trainSize: modelInputs.Count(),
                 horizon: 10,
                 confidenceLowerBoundColumn: "LowerBoundScore",
                 confidenceUpperBoundColumn: "UpperBoundScore",
                 confidenceLevel:0.95f
                );
```

Prices Varies on the basis of factors and previous data
But It Does not take any Impacting factor
I have Also Tried :

```
 var dataProcessPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(new[] { new InputOutputColumnPair("name", "name") })
                                      .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("Date_tf", "Date"))
                                      .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", new[] { "name", "Date_tf", "priceB" }));
            // Set the training algorithm 
            var trainer = mlContext.Regression.Trainers.FastTree(labelColumnName: "priceA", featureColumnName: "Features");
```

But it does not makes any sense for getting data for specific date If changes my Date Variable to string it works but does not works 
if I make my variable data
What Can be the best Algorithm or technique for predicting the future prices on the basis of previous data and Impacting Factors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your date column to integers. Check out this sample to see how you could accomplish this:

https://github.com/gvashishtha/time-series-mlnet/blob/master/time-series-forecast.ipynb